# ADT Plugin not showing up in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, fedora, adt

I have recently installed Fedora 16 and I am trying to get ADT up and running from scratch on it.  It's a 64bit system.  I have installed AVD's under Ubuntu about 5 times (Hardy Heron through Lucid Lynx).  I often ran into trouble, but this problem does not want to go away and I'm about 3 days into ripping my hair out.  If someone here can't help me fix this, I'm going back to Ubuntu.

I followed all of the instructions at this link:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development

Although I can run an AVD (from the command line, with the method used inside that tut) and all of the demos apps work great inside it...

If you go to:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/HOWTO_Setup_Android_Development#Hello_Fedora

and just a few more lines down, you will see where I get hung up.

**THIS IS MY PRIMARY PROBLEM:**

I cannot start a new android project because it is not available under File/New/Project where it is supposed to be.

I have tried uninstalling via command line

```
yum remove eclipse-*
```

I have tried removing through "add/remove programs" under Activities.  I've removed just the Eclipse-Platfom selection and I've tried removing absolutely everything installed with Eclipse in it's name.  I've re-installed with yum and with the Add/Remove Programs tools (yes I know it's just a front end).  I have double scoured over every step to make sure I spelled things right.

The ONLY thing I can think of is that maybe I am not changing the PATH variables correctly.  This is what I entered:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ultrajones/SDK:$HOME/ultrajones/SDK/tools
export PATH

# For SDK version r_08 and higher, also add this for adb:
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/ultrajones/SDK/platform-tools
export PATH
```

Obviously, ultrajones is my username, but I've never had "formal" training with make files and PATHs and all that stuff so I wouldn't know a good one from a bad one - I just fill in the blanks.

How can I get Android to appear as a selection under new projects in Eclipse?

I hate to throw out an entire operating system based on this problem, but that is where I am at right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple weeks ago I found the answer to my own question.  I posted the solution on my blog. I finally remembered to come back and answer my question.  The entry in this link describes the entire process of installing the ADT in Eclipse 3.7.1 on Fedora 16

[My blog post about installing Android Dev Tools in Fedora.](http://ultraopengl.blogspot.com/2012/01/setup-android-development-in-eclipse.html)